# Not able to understand a function which uses app.logger.getLogger( ) in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am going thrugh a react project and I came through few lines of code that I am not able to understand. I tried searching for it, but still didn't find anything. The function is as shown below:

```
export const getLocalizedStrings = (componentName) => {
  app.logger.getLogger().info('Comp Name' + componentName);
  var strings = getStrings(localizedStrings[componentName].strings,
    localizedStrings[componentName].common);
  return new LocalizedStrings(strings);
};
```

So, in the function, the line :

```
 app.logger.getLogger().info('Comp Name' + componentName);
```

Here, I am not able to understand what's happening. I can see that `app` is not being imported anywhere in the file.So, I guess it is something that is in-built in javascript.I am sorry if this is something very basic, but I am new to Javascript and React, so can anyone please help me understand what is happening in this line `app.logger.getLogger().info('Comp Name' + componentName);`? Also, if anyone could help me understand what going on with the overall function it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:** The code for the whole file is :

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization';
import { getStrings } from '../Common/Localization/commonStrings';

const localizedStrings = {
  identityDrawerComponent: {
    strings: {
      en: {
        emailErrorMsg : 'This email address is already registered ',
        yourAccntSettings : 'Your Account Settings',
        emailValidationSuccessMsg : ' is now your login email address. If you need to change it, you can edit it below',
        emailValidationErrorMsg : 'The email address has not been added because either the link to verify your email address has expired, or the email address has already been added to you contact information',
        activationError :'Activation Error'
      }
    },
    common: ['globalError']
  },
  identityNameComponent: {
    strings: {
      en: {
        firstName : 'First Name',
        lastName : 'Last Name',
        editName: 'Edit Name'
      },
    },
    common: ['cancel','save']
  },
  identityEmailComponent: {
    strings : {
      en: {
        editUserId : 'Edit User ID',
        logInEmail : 'Log in email',
        pendVerification : 'Pending Verification:',
        noPendVerification : 'No pending Email',
        confirmChanges : 'Confirm change of User ID to',
        pendVerificationDescription : 'A verification email has been sent to your updated email address. Please follow the instructions in the email within 24 hours, or the update will be cancelled.'
      },
    },
    common: ['cancel','save','yes','no']
  },
  identityPasswordComponent: {
    strings : {
      en: {
        password : 'Password',
        editPassword : 'Edit Password'
      },
    },
    common: ['cancel','save']
  },
  identityLanguageComponent: {
    strings : {
      en: {
        language : 'Language',
        editLanguage : 'Edit Language',
        languageHelp : 'You may choose to set a preferred language. When content is available in your preferred language, it will be displayed based on this setting; otherwise, content in English will be displayed.'
      },
    },
    common: ['cancel','save']
  }
};

export const getLocalizedStrings = (componentName) => {
  app.logger.getLogger().info('Comp Name' + componentName);
  var strings = getStrings(localizedStrings[componentName].strings,
    localizedStrings[componentName].common);
  return new LocalizedStrings(strings);
};
```

Comment: React is JavaScript; if the above code runs, then `app` must be defined somewhere. React has no built-in `app` Object.

Comment: *"I can see that `app` is not being imported anywhere in the file. So, I guess it is something that is in-built in javascript."* Nope, it's not in-built in JavaScript or React. Something elsewhere in that code must be creating it as a global.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and Chris G , I have added the complete js file in an edit above, but I am not able to understand from where app might be coming. Can you guys please check once.

Comment: @pranami - It's not being created by that code. It's being created (as a global) by other code you haven't shown. You'll have to find that code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ohh, okay. Let me check where it might be defined.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I have one doubt. How are those global constants added in javascript. I mean is it created initially while the project is created , so that all the newly created files inside the project can have access to those global functions and constants?

Comment: @pranami - At global scope, a variable declaration creates a global variable which is accessible anywhere within the page/app. You can also create a global *not* at global scope by assigning to a property on the global object, which you can access in several ways (for instance, by using the `window` global, which is a reference to the global object on browsers). So at global scope, `var app` or `let app` or `const app` create globals, or anywhere `window.app = ...` creates a global, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay. Thanks a lot for the explanation. I will go through the project and check where `app` is defined. Also, will have to dig deeper into javascript and reactjs. Anyways, thanks for your help.